# displaying category and subcategories in one drop down select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a select like this(it is a drop down select input) :

[image]

as you can see when the select opens it display main categories which by clicking on each category the sub categories will be shown . also you can click on the tick to choose the current category and sub category.
Also , when sub categories of a category is being displayed , there is two item at the top. one is the tick and the other one is back which by clicking on it , you could see the main categories again.

How can create selects like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you build `ul`'s in each `li` of the main `ul`

Comment: There is no way to do this in a standard `<select>` the closest you will get to representing this in a select list is `<optgroup>` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Comment: @Jon There is a website which has done that.The address is this "divar.ir" .it's in the search section .

Comment: I find out that it's using chosen-master . But some changed has been made to that .

Answer (score 1):

this is the html part that you can use to have a menu and sub-menu.

```
<body class="no-js">
    <nav id="topNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">Nav Link 1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">Nav Link 2</a>
                <ul>  
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 1">Sub Nav Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 2">Sub Nav Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 3">Sub Nav Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 4">Sub Nav Link 4</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 5">Sub Nav Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>                
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">Nav Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">Nav Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">Nav Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: @Avanish I want to make it inside drop down select not just a menu

Comment: you can use by creating nested <ul> <li> </li> <li> <ul> <li> </li> <li> </li> </ul> </li> </ul>